# JSTL variables not being displayed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl, netbeans-7

I have been doing a couple of Spring tutorials and both have failed at the stage where the view prints out variables using JSTL.

The view:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head><title><fmt:message key="title"/></title></head>
  <body>
   <h1><fmt:message key="heading"/></h1>
   <p><fmt:message key="greeting"/><c:out value="${model.now}"/></p>
   <h3>Products</h3>
   <c:forEach items="${model.products}" var="prod">
    <c:out value="${prod.name}"/> <i>$<c:out value="${prod.number}"/></i><br><br>
   </c:forEach>
  </body>
 </html>
```

The fmt:message parts display on my page properly, but the ${model.now} part is not being rendered.

The above is on a page "hello.jsp", that includes "include.jsp" which contains:

```
taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
```

JSTL is in my libraries folder (I'm using NetBeans)

Anyone know why this keeps happening and absolutely nothing is rendered?

Here is the controller:

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse            response)
throws ServletException, IOException 
    { 
    String now = (new java.util.Date()).toString();
    logger.info("Returning hello view with " + now);

    Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    myModel.put("now", now);
    myModel.put("product", this.productManager.getProducts());
    return new ModelAndView("hello", "model", myModel);
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
si:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener- class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: howz the form tag specified?

Comment: You need to show us the spring controller you are using

Comment: Post how you have specified form:form tag or whatever in your jsp.

Comment: Prasad: there is no form:form tag? Currently all I am doing is declaring some products in the servlet and then attempting to display them on the page

Comment: Could you please post the entire hello.jsp (along with the taglibs) and also web.xml?

Comment: Your view doesn't have include.jsp   ;)

Comment: Have now added entire hello.jsp and the web.xml - view does have include.jsp have edited to display that now

Comment: Include form:form tag as shown below and try.

Comment: You mention `${model.now}` in your remarks, but the code says `${now}`. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: Do you have your code on GitHub?

Comment: Afraid not @geoand, i'm simply following a simple Spring MVC tutorial... I've abandoned other tutorials for the same reason, whenever a ${} comes up, I hit a brick wall :'(

Comment: Which servlet container are you using?

Comment: I'm a noob so not too sure what you mean by servlet container. I'm using Glassfish server

Comment: What version of Glassfish?

Comment: Have managed to fix it (see answer below) - was a url mapping error all along... ARGH.

Answer (score 1):

Have successfully discovered why this wasn't working:

I was incorrectly mapping to my hello view in my servlet, it was loading the page but was not correctly loading the model, hence why there were no variables being displayed

Comment: what do you mean by loading page and not model?

Answer (score 0):

Just have form tag specified as:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    </head>
    <body">
    <form:form id="model" modelAttribute="model">
        <h1><fmt:message key="heading"/></h1>
        <p><fmt:message key="greeting"/><c:out value="${model.now}"/></p>
    </form:form>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference I'm afraid :(

Comment: Do you have jstl 1.2 jar in your classpath?

Comment: Also, once you specify form:form, access the "now" by ${model.now}

Comment: Yup, no difference... :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the following taglib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

And also `<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>`

Finally make sure that you have JSTL 1.2 taglib dependencies on your classpath

Comment: brainZap specified that c tag is there in include.jsp

Comment: Adding `<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>` did not work, however at the moment all I can see is JSTL 1.1